# JTable inside JTable is not rendering

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to put **JTable** inside to **JTable**. Everything is working fine I can get all *track* info and also succesfully put it into *model* and *insideTable*, the only problem is I can't get it to render.

Even tried to set *insideTable* foreground color to red, but still couldn't see any change

```
  table.setDefaultRenderer(List.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            String[] columns = {"Name","Duration","Location"};
            List<Track> tracks = (ArrayList<Track>) value;

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columns,0);
            JTable insideTable = new JTable(model);

            for(Track t: tracks){
                String[] r = {t.getName(),t.getDuration(),t.getLocation()};
                model.addRow(r);
            }
            model.fireTableDataChanged();
            insideTable.setVisible(true);

            return insideTable;
        }
    });
```

This is how it looks.

[image: Using custom render]

This one is using default render.

[image: Using default render]

**EDIT:** *Solved*

```
 table.setDefaultRenderer(List.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            String[] columns = {"Name","Duration","Location"};
            List<Track> tracks = (ArrayList<Track>) value;

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columns,0);
            JTable insideTable = new JTable(model);

            for(Track t: tracks){
                String[] r = {t.getName(),t.getDuration(),t.getLocation()};
                model.addRow(r);
            }
            table.setRowHeight(row, 20 + (15 * insideTable.getRowCount()));
            JScrollPane columnFix = new JScrollPane(insideTable);
            columnFix.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

            return columnFix;
        }
    });
```

[image: Fixed]

Comment: Why do you want to have two tables inside each other? Why don't you show just another table, if one tracklist is chosen?

Comment: @DFJ I have specific requirements. I know I can just put JButton there, but that wouldn't look good.

Comment: Post an [mcve] that demonstrates your problem. So forget about your real app and create a simple test case. That is create a DefaultTableModel with some dummy data and store this model in the main TableModel. Then write a custom renderer to display the DefaultTableModel in a JTable. The point of doing this is now you can post a simple example with just a frame and a JTable. We don't care about your Track class and related data.

Comment: Also consider adding `ListSelectionListener` and displaying the selected table in a dialog or adjacent component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved it giving the row custom height, and then fixed columnNames which have not been showing up.

```
table.setRowHeight(row, 20 + (15 * insideTable.getRowCount()));
JScrollPane columnFix = new JScrollPane(insideTable);
columnFix.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```